# mysql select where array in array

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i am doing a table with multiple keyboards or tags,
like this:

```
id |   keyboards
===+================================================
1  |     picture,mountain,animals 
2  |     water,mountain
3  |     sound, mountain
4  |     water, picture, mountain, space, other
```

and i want to make a select.

**SELECT id from table where (mountain,picture,space) in keyboards**;

result must be:
1 row

id

> 4.

please help me.

Comment: Do you mean "keywords" instead of "keyboards"?

Comment: sorry, i mean "keywords" instead of "keyboards", and normalizing was the best solution, now i have three tables, and for the moment it works fine, thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have poor database normalization. Best way to do is to create a table `Keyboards`

```
CREATE TABLE Keyboards
(
    Keyboard_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    KeyBoardName VARCHAR(25),
    CONSTRAINT kbrd_pk PRIMARY KEY (Keyboard_ID),
    CONSTRAINT kbrd_uq UNIQUE(KeyboardName)
)

CREATE table Tags
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Keyboard_ID int,
    CONSTRAINT tags_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT tags_pk FOREIGN KEY (keyboard_ID) REFERENCES keyboards(keyboard_ID)
)
```

then reference `keyboards.id` in `tags` table.

Then you can do this query,

```
SELECT id,
FROM   tags a
       INNER JOIN keyboards b
           ON a.keyboard_id = b.keyboard_ID
WHERE  b.keyboardName IN ('mountain','picture','space')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.keyboardName) = 3
```

but to answer you question, you can simply do this

```
select *
from tags
where keyboards like concat('%','mountain','%') AND
      keyboards like concat('%','picture','%') and
      keyboards like concat('%','space','%')
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21233/1)

Comment: This doesn't work when the tags are `'mountain','mountain','space'`:  Instead use `HAVING SUM(b.keyboardName='mountain') AND SUM(b.keyboardName='picture') AND SUM(b.keyboardName='space')`

Comment: why will you search for duplicate tag? if so, the two `mountains` are different?

Comment: @GavinTowey that can eliminated using `HAVING COUNT(distinct tag)=3`

Comment: sure, but in general the pattern I showed is far more flexible.  For example what if you wanted to search where it had two specific tags, and didn't have another?

Comment: Agreed that normalizing the data is the best option.  However, I suggest replacing your `like concat('%'...` with `'RLIKE CONCAT('(^|[ ,])', 'space', '(,|$)')`.  That will match `space` wherever it appears in the OP's (inconsistent!) array catenation, and won't match everything `%space%` would (`spaces` and `triple-space`, for instance).